# How to create a def in python that pick a specific "value" and then make a new dict like this

Tags: python

```
myDict ={"key1" : "val1",
         "key2" : "val2",
         "key3" : "val3",
         "key4" : "x",
         "key5" : "x"
         }
```

I need a def in python that take (myDict and "x")
and then return a newDict like this:

```
newDict ={"key4":"x",
          "key5":"x"
         }
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "take (myDict and "x") "

Comment: This can be done with a simple dictionary comprehension that iterates over `myDict.items()`

Comment: @CaptainCaveman He means that the parameters to the function are `myDict` and the value `"x"` to search for in the dictionary values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find(dictionary, key):
    return dict(zip((p:=list(filter(lambda x: dictionary[x] == key, dictionary))), key * len(p)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```py
def find_keys_by_value(myDict, value):
    newDict = {}
    for key in myDict:
        if myDict[key] == value:
            newDict[key] = myDict[key]
    return newDict
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following approach

```
myDict ={"key1" : "val1",
         "key2" : "val2",
         "key3" : "val3",
         "key4" : "x",
         "key5" : "x"
         }


def new_dict_by_value(_my_dict, _value):
    new_dict = {key: value for key, value in _my_dict.items() if value == _value}
    return new_dict


print(new_dict_by_value(myDict, 'x'))
####
{'key4': 'x', 'key5': 'x'}
```